# Why does setting a variable to open an exported txt delete it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Everytime I set this variable, the exported txt file is instantly deleted.

```
OutFile1 = open('C:/Saves/Popventure/Save1.txt', 'wt')
```

As soon as the console reads this code, the txt is empty. I've tested, and turns out it is this exact line that causes the issue. How do I stop the code from activating, or deleting what's inside the txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [official docummentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) `'w'` means

> open for writing, truncating the file first

If you want to keep a current content you can open file in the append mode:

```
open('/path/to/file', 'at')
```

it means

> open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists

Answer (score 1):

Read these carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466036/1453822 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466037/1453822

By using the `w` mode you tell Python to truncate the file if it exists.